# paramiko ssh does not work with start cmd.exe "" "application.exe" commands in batch script

Tags: batch-file, paramiko

I am trying to run a batch script from paramiko ssh.

the batch script is like this:

```
start cmd.exe /k "cd C:\\Users\\Administrator\\iometer\\ && C:\\Users\\Administrator\\iometer\\IOmeter.exe /c C:\\Users\\Administrator\\iometer\\new_config.icf /r C:\\Users\\Administrator\\iometer\\iometer_result_v.csv"
```

If I run the batch script locally it works, but when I trigger the same batch script from `paramiko` `exec_command()` it doesn't start the `IOMeter.exe` application.

1. I tried giving relative path and then with absolute path. It did not help.
2. I tried running the whole batch script command from `exec_command()` itself and even that did not start the application in remote machine.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is, if we run any batch script with exec_command in paramiko python, it executes command and immediately kills the session and all dependent sessions (or child sessions) opened by that exec_command sessions.

To resolve this issue, you can trigger the same batch script from powershell and add wait at the end. Or create a PowerShell script (temp.ps1) and add the command to run the batch script as a process.

sample batch file looks like this:(I am using notepad here for security concerns, but actually I am running a tool which runs IO stress on different disks parallelly and logs output to the file)

```
start cmd.exe /k \"cd C:\\Users\\Administrator\\automate && C:\\Users\\Administrator\\automate\\notepad.exe &exit"
start cmd.exe /k \"cd C:\\Users\\Administrator\\automate && C:\\Users\\Administrator\\automate\\notepad.exe &exit"
start cmd.exe /k \"cd C:\\Users\\Administrator\\automate && C:\\Users\\Administrator\\automate\\notepad.exe &exit"
```

Sample powershell script looks like this:

```
start-process 'cmd.exe' -ArgumentList "/c C:\\Users\\Administrator\\automate\\temp_batch.bat &exit" -Wait
```

So, total we have a batch script and a powershell run the batch script as a process.
In python just run this powershell script using paramiko exec_command.

```
cmd = "powershell -file C:\\Users\\Administrator\\automate\\temp3.ps1"
```

Sample python script would look something like this:

```
import paramiko
hostname = 'x.x.x.x'
port = 22
username = 'user'
password = 'pwd'
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname,port,username,password)
cmd = "powershell -file C:\\Users\\Administrator\\diskio\\temp3.ps1"
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command(cmd)
outlines=stdout.readlines()
result=''.join(outlines)
print (result)
print(stderr.readlines())
ssh.close()
```